# Malloc почему-то не работает

Tags: c, функции, динамические-массивы, malloc

Почему-то НЕ выполняется malloc и как следствие

```
(*value_comblock)[1] = 0;
```

не выполняется

Весь код

```
#pragma hdrstop
#pragma argsused

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <windows.h> //FOR WINDOWS ONLY

#ifdef _WIN32
#include <tchar.h>
#else
typedef char _TCHAR;
#define _tmain main
#endif



// Структура двогичного (бинарного) дерева

struct btree {
    double data; // данные
    struct btree *left; // левая ветвь
    struct btree *right; // правая ветвь
    struct btree *parent; // родитель
};

bool read_arg(char**, signed long long int**); // сигн. ф. считывания команд

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) {

    /* ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ПЕРЕМЕННЫЕ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ */

    // Динамические массивы
    char *command_comblock; // Массив комманд
    signed long long int *value_comblock; // Массив значений

    /* ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ КОММАНДЫ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ */

    // Включаем русский в консоли
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251); // FOR WINDOWS ONLY

    // Ввод и анализ на верность комманд
    if (read_arg(&command_comblock, &value_comblock) != true) {
        // Если что-то пошло не так при вводе в первый раз (попробуем еще разок)
        if (read_arg(&command_comblock, &value_comblock) != true) {
            // Что-то явно не так со вводом (тест на похмелье :D)

            // ScreenCleaner
            system("cls"); // FOR WINDOWS ONLY
            // system("clear"); //FOR LINUX ONLY

            // Выдача ошибки
            return 315;
        }
    }

    // Разбор введеных аргументов
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

bool read_arg(char** command_comblock, signed long long int** value_comblock) {
    // ПЕРЕМЕННЫЕ
    char temp;

    // Первоначальное выделение места массивам
    if ((*command_comblock = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char))) == NULL) {
        printf("Realloc Error! [command_comblock]");
        return false;
    }

    if ((*value_comblock = (signed long long int *)malloc((sizeof(signed long long int)))) == NULL) {
        printf("Realloc Error! [value_comblock]");
        return false;
    }

    // Непосредственное считывание
    printf("Вводите комманды, как в k806.ru [Для Win. Ctrl+Z = EOF]\n");

    printf("%d", sizeof(*value_comblock));

    (*value_comblock)[0] = 0; // Количество операций
    (*value_comblock)[1] = 0; // Количество значений

    while (temp != EOF) {
        temp = getchar();
        switch (temp) {

            // Операция вывода дерева
        case 'p':
            (*value_comblock)[0] = (*value_comblock)[0] + 1; // Кол-во операций

            if ((*command_comblock = (char*)realloc(*command_comblock,
            (((*value_comblock)[0])*sizeof(char)))) == NULL) {
                printf("Realloc Error! [command_comblock]");
                return false;
            }

            (*command_comblock)[(*value_comblock)[0] - 1] = temp;
        break;

        //Операция "вставка в дерево"
    case '+':
        (*value_comblock)[0] = (*value_comblock)[0] + 1; // Кол-во операций
        (*value_comblock)[1] = (*value_comblock)[1] + 1; // Кол-во значений

        if ((*command_comblock = (char*)realloc(*command_comblock,
            (((*value_comblock)[0])*sizeof(char)))) == NULL) {
            printf("Realloc Error! [command_comblock]");
            return false;
        }

        if ((*value_comblock = (char*)realloc(*value_comblock,
            (((*value_comblock)[0]+2)*sizeof(char)))) == NULL) {
            printf("Realloc Error! [command_comblock]");
            return false;
        }

        (*command_comblock)[(*value_comblock)[0] - 1] = temp;
        scanf("%d", &(*value_comblock)[(*value_comblock)[1] + 1]);

        break;
    }

}

return true;
}
```

Comment: (*value_comblock)[1] = 0; - при копировании не заметил

Comment: Смотрите комментарий  //Операция "вставка в дерево"

Comment: (2*sizeof(signed long long int) - НЕ ПОМОГАЕТ!!!

Comment: Исправил (((*value_comblock)[0]+2)*sizeof(char)))) на  (((*value_comblock)[0]+2)*sizeof(signed long long int))))

Comment: Но все это пока не дает эффекта, программа упорно отказывается писать в любую (кроме нулевой) ячейку массива

Comment: Каким образом она "отказывается"? Возникает ошибка доступа к памяти? Если да, то на какой строке. Если же ошибок доступа нет, то ошибка кроется в логике вашей программы (сами пишите не в ту ячейку).

Comment: Может вам не стоит тратить время на динамический массив - обьявить статический елементов на 1000.

Comment: Настоятельно советую реализовать слежение за колличеством елементов в массиве и поставить assert-ы на доступ к елементу массива - и отладкой отловить случаи выхода за пределы массива.

Comment: Если не хотите писать кучу проверок - возможно библиотечная `vector<>` вам поможет с меньшими затратами исправить ошибки вашего кода.

Comment: Вектор сделать невозможно, т.к. задание именно дин. массив

Comment: Не срабатывает  (*value_comblock)[1] = 0; // Количество значений

Comment: Т.е. не добавляется при этом ячейка массива в дебаггере, а зн. под нее тупо не выделено место

Comment: @SlimRG Значит это проблемы дебагера или вашего использования его. Если программа не падает на этой строке, значит память выделена и вы просто не можете/не умеете её посмотреть.

Comment: Да, это была подгоревшая планка RAM - сорри народ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот здесь выделяется память под один элемент:

```
if ((*value_comblock = (signed long long int *)malloc((sizeof(signed long long int)))) == NULL) {
        printf("Realloc Error! [value_comblock]");
        return false;
    }
```

А ниже по коду попытка обращения ко второму элементу:

```
(*value_comblock)[1] = 0;
```

поэтому и ошибка.

Comment: (2*sizeof(signed long long int)) - НЕ ПОМОГАЕТ!!!
(Только что попробовал - все та же фигня)

Comment: @SlimRG У вас ещё ошибка во втором `realloc` - вместо `sizeof(char)` должен быть `sizeof(signed long long int)`.

Comment: Спасибо, но все равно не присваиваются кроме нулевой в другие ячейки массива

Comment: @SlimRG Ещё ошибка в `scanf` - вместо `%d` надо писать `%I64d` - у вас же массив 64-х битных чисел.

Comment: @SlimRG С учётом замечаний, запись в массив `value_comblock` работает нормально - в первых 2-х ячейках счётчики, в остальных - введённые пользователем значения.

Comment: Странно... у меня только нулевая ячейка в value_combloc растет, а остальные по дебаггеру отсутствуют

Comment: https://yadi.sk/i/vN61u1z13UynfJ

Comment: Можете посмотреть - может чего проглядел?

Comment: @SlimRG Может у вас дебагер так себе? Воспользуйтесь принтами на крайний случай. Я тестировал в CodeBlocks (mingw-w64 gcc 7.3).

Comment: Дебаггер от Qt ((mingw-w64 х64 gcc 6.5)- раньше проблем не было

Comment: Путь сделаем (*value_comblock)[1] = 999;

Comment: Он должен был при этом отобразить ячейку массива [1] равную 999

Comment: А он, ска, пишет [0] = 0, первую воодще не видит!!!!

Comment: Хотя с command_comblock все норм

Comment: @SlimRG Используйте `printf("%I64d", (*value_comblock)[1]);`

Comment: Вставил 2а принта до и после (*value_comblock)[1] = 999;
Сначала напечатал 40, после вылетел с access denied

Comment: А второй раз сначало 40 потом 5432

Comment: Магия какая-то...

Comment: @SlimRG: Вы несете какую-то несусветицу. Что такое "по дебаггеру отсутствуют"???

Comment: В `realloc` для `*value_comblock` умножение делается на `sizeof(char)`... Вот это вот манера делать явное приведение типа на результат функции аллокации и манера использовать имена типов под `sizeof` - всегда красный флаг, предупреждающий, что код будет набит такими ошибками.

Answer (score 1):

Что попросили -

```
*value_comblock = (signed long long int *)malloc((sizeof(signed long long int)))
```

то и дал - `sizeof(signed long long int)` байт, на один элемент...